# Why am I getting an ERROR 1064 when executing this select with subselect?

Tags: mysql, subquery

### My task given

> The given SQL creates a Song table and inserts some
> songs. The first SELECT statement selects songs released after 1992.
> The second SELECT statement selects the release year for song with ID
> 800.
>
> Create a third query that combines the two existing queries. The first
> SELECT should be the outer query, and the second SELECT should be the
> subquery. The ORDER BY clause should appear after the subquery.

```
ID INT,
  Title VARCHAR(60),
  Artist VARCHAR(60),
  ReleaseYear INT,
  Genre VARCHAR(20),
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT INTO Song VALUES
  (100, 'Hey Jude', 'Beatles', 1968, 'pop rock'),
  (200, 'You Belong With Me', 'Taylor Swift', 2008, 'country pop'),
  (300, 'You\'re Still the One', 'Shania Twain', 1998, 'country pop'),
  (400, 'Need You Now', 'Lady Antebellum', 2011, 'country pop'),
  (500, 'You\'ve Lost That Lovin\' Feeling', 'The Righteous Brothers', 1964, 'R&B'),
  (600, 'That\'s The Way Love Goes', 'Janet Jackson', 1993, 'R&B'),
  (700, 'Smells Like Teen Spirit', 'Nirvana', 1991, 'grunge'),
  (800, 'Even Flow', 'Pearl Jam', 1992, 'grunge'),
  (900, 'Black Hole Sun', 'Soundgarden', 1994, 'grunge');

SELECT *
FROM Song
WHERE ReleaseYear > 1992
ORDER BY ReleaseYear;

SELECT ReleaseYear
FROM Song 
WHERE ID = 800;
```

### My attempt so far

```
SELECT ReleaseYear
FROM Song
WHERE ReleaseYear > 1992
   (Select ReleaseYear
   FROM Song 
   WHERE ID = 800)
Order by ReleaseYear DESC;
```

I dont understand what is wrong with my query and subquery. Every time I try to run it I get: `ERROR 1064`, indicating that it does not understand my code.

Comment: Your create table is missing a bit in the beginning

Comment: `WHERE` condition expression `ReleaseYear > 1992 (Select ...)` doesn't make sense. What do you think it does & why? A [mre] includes clear specification & explanation. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.) Don't just dump wrong code.

Answer (score 0):

To get the release year for songs released after `1992` and for the song with ID `800`, you can use a UNION ALL operator to combine the results of two SELECT queries:

```
SELECT ReleaseYear 
FROM Song 
WHERE ReleaseYear > 1992
UNION ALL
SELECT ReleaseYear 
FROM Song 
WHERE ID = 800;
```

db<>fiddle [output](https://dbfiddle.uk/236KGr1r)

Answer (score 0):

The instructions are not clear but I suspect the intended query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Song
WHERE ReleaseYear > 1992
OR ReleaseYear = (
    SELECT ReleaseYear
    FROM Song
    WHERE ID = 800
)
ORDER BY ReleaseYear;
```